# Заглавная буква или строчная?

Tags: кавычки, дефис, строчная, заглавная, раздельно

Лингвисты и картёжники, у меня вопрос в написании названий покера. О/омаха, Т/техасский Х/холдеми и Д/дро... Как вообще будет писаться? Нужны ли кавычки или дефис? Как будет правильно: «О/омаха(-)покер» и «Д/дро(-)покер»?

Answer (score 1):

Возможные варианты: ***Омаха, Омаха-покер, Техасский холдем, Дро-покер.***
Родовое слово «покер» (приложение) ставится на второе место и пишется через дефис.

**Пояснение**

1. В правописании составных имен собственных можно выделить **тематическую группу,** где возможны колебания в выборе формы письма. Сюда относятся некоторые топонимические имена, а также названия предметов (орденов и медалей, бытовой и промышленной техники, растений и животных, вин, продуктов и др.). В эту же группу можно отнести и названия карточных игр.

Характерной особенностью этой группы является наличие **вариантов письма:** Форма 1. Прописная буква, без кавычек (в специальной литературе). Форма 2. Прописная буква с кавычками. Форма 3. Строчная буква с кавычками. Форма 4. Строчная буква без кавычек.

Форма 3 и форма 4 фактически относятся к нарицательным существительным. Наличие кавычек в форме 3 обычно говорит о том, что данное слово не является общеизвестным термином.

Эти группы можно рассмотреть на примере названий для вина: (1) десертное вино Цинандали; (2) вино «Солнечная долина», «Бычья кровь»; (3) «бордо», «бургундское»; (4) кагор, мадера.

2. **Эта же система** просматривается в названии карточных игр. Если почитать литературу на эту тему, то можно увидеть наличие вариантов с прописными и строчными буквами.

**Слово «покер»** – нарицательное существительное, но названия могут считаться как собственными, так и нарицательными, причем варианты иногда встречаются в одной статье. В более официальных названиях (именах собственных) первое слово пишется с прописной буквы, но эти же названия могут писаться со строчной буквы как нарицательные, и это будет авторским выбором.

3. В целом система условно строится как **видо-родовая классификация**, где цепочка родовых названий (строчная буква) заканчиваются видовым названием (прописная буква). Поэтому здесь довольно **свободная система письма**, но надо хорошо понимать ее условности. В этом случае знатоки этой игры могут даже лучше ориентироваться, чем языковеды.

Вот чем Омаха-покер отличается от Омаха-холдема? Возможно, **покер** – это старшее родовое название, а **холдем, дро-покер** (как его разновидности) – это тоже нарицательные названия, если они в свою очередь имеют несколько видов. Но в то же время они могут писаться и с прописной буквы, если эти виды не учитывать. **Отсюда такое разнообразие письма.**

4. **Кавычки** могут использоваться, но такая запись менее популярна, а роль их неясна. Понятно, к примеру, такое письмо: карточная игра «Техасский холдем». Встречаются записи "Техасский Холдем", «Омара Холдем», тогда кавычки лучше поставить. Но выбор прописной буквы не очень ясен, так как холдем используется и в других названиях; соответственно он ближе к нарицательному существительному.
5. **Примеры предложений**

**Техасский холдем** (или просто холдем, от англ. hold’em.) – самая популярная разновидность спортивного покера в Северной Америке и Европе.
Обычно, в техасский холдем принято играть 52-карточной колодой

**Дро-покер** – это любой вариант покера, в котором каждый игрок получает полную руку перед первым раундом ставок, а затем развивает руку для последующих раундов, заменяя или "вытягивая" карты.

Все разновидности покера, в которых присутствует приставка «дро» обозначают, что в них имеется возможность обмена карт. Есть две разновидности 5-карточного дро-покера. (Здесь дро-покер является нарицательным названием, как и покер.)

Достаточно популярная разновидность покера, **Омаха** отличается от холдема тем, что в нее играют 4 карманными картами, а не 2.

https://playingstars.club/raznovidnosti-pokera/